# Repurpose a form redirect

Tags: forms, redirection

I was wondering — as I am unable to seemingly find the right keywords to search for — if anyone out there knows of an existing Drupal 7 function to do this. It seems like it would make sense for it to exist already.

Basically I have a form that already has a redirect value applied to it's `$form_state` — the construction currently is as follows. I do not have control of this value, it is set by LoginToboggan.

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array (
  'user/awaiting-auth',
  array(
    'query' => array(),
  )
);
```

However, I would like to step in and redirect to my own stop-gap page. After the form on that stop-gap page has been submitted I'd like the original redirect to occur. Obviously I can code this transformation, what I have currently is:

```
/// check to see if we would have had a destination
if ( !empty($form_state['redirect']) ) {
  /// if it's an array, then handle as array ( $path, $options )
  if ( is_array( $form_state['redirect'] ) ) {
    $dest = url($form_state['redirect'][0], $form_state['redirect'][1]);
  }
  /// if string, treat as path?query
  else if ( is_string( $form_state['redirect'] ) ) {
    $dest = $form_state['redirect'];
  }
  else {
    $dest = '';
  }
  /// build our redirect options
  $options = array(
    'query' => array(
      'destination' => $dest,
    ),
  );
}
else {
  $options = array();
}
/// recreate our redirection based on where we want to go now, and where we will go next.
$form_state['redirect'] = array( "node/{$form_node->nid}", $options );
```

Whilst this works, to a certain degree, there are two issues:

1. The redirect array containing `user/awaiting-auth`, when passed through `url`, is returned as `/user/awaiting-auth`. This is fine if used directly as part of a `drupal_goto()`. However, when fed back as a `destination` value, the ultimate location the user ends up at is `//user/awaiting-auth`. I could trim the prefixed `/` but this feels clunky.
2. I am currently handling different outcomes if the initial redirect value is an array or a string (possible values as far as I can discern). However, there may be other constructions I do not know about, or a future version of Drupal may change the redirect/url array construction; this would be where an exising Drupal function would be best.

What I'm looking for I guess is something like this:

```
drupal_chain_redirect( $destination, $old_destination );
```

Where `$destination` could be a string or array, and the same for `$old_destination`. It would return an array structure ready to be set to `$form_state['redirect']`. It seems like this would be a frequently occuring request when developing complex modules that may interplay and step on each others toes.

Any ideas?